# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in FORALL statement

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying the following

```
FORALL l_loop_cntr IN 1..l_count
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' INSERT INTO ' ||c_table || ' VALUES l_NE_BILL_REPORTS_table (:1) ' USING
l_loop_cntr;
```

my table name is dynamic.

but it gives the error
Compilation errors for PROCEDURE PL_OWNER.TEST_BULK

Error: PLS-00435: DML statement without BULK In-BIND cannot be used inside FORALL
Line: 27
Text: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' INSERT INTO ' ||c_table || ' VALUES l_NE_BILL_REPORTS_table (:1) ' USING l_loop_cntr;

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the collection in the `using` clause; the index on its own doesn't mean anything. You haven't shown what the collection is called, so substitute your actual name for `col`; I assume `l_count` is the same as `col.last`:

```
FORALL l_loop_cntr IN my_col.first..my_col.last
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || c_table
    || ' VALUES l_NE_BILL_REPORTS_table (:1)'
  USING my_col(l_loop_cntr);
```